# Jhipster Registry 4.0.0 exception pre-packaged WAR

Tags: java, microservices, jhipster, jhipster-registry

When I run Gateway I get this error on Registry service.

```
2018-07-31 11:23:33.472 ERROR 1617 --- [get_localhost-3] c.n.e.cluster.ReplicationTaskProcessor   : It seems to be 
a socket read timeout exception, it will retry later. if it continues to happen and some eureka node occupied all the cpu time, you should set property 'eureka.server.peer-node-read-timeout-ms' to a bigger value

com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:187)
        at com.netflix.eureka.cluster.DynamicGZIPContentEncodingFilter.handle(DynamicGZIPContentEncodingFilter.java:48)
        at com.netflix.discovery.EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.handle(EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.java:27)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
        at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:570)
        at com.netflix.eureka.transport.JerseyReplicationClient.submitBatchUpdates(JerseyReplicationClient.java:116
)
        at com.netflix.eureka.cluster.ReplicationTaskProcessor.process(ReplicationTaskProcessor.java:80)
        at com.netflix.eureka.util.batcher.TaskExecutors$BatchWorkerRunnable.run(TaskExecutors.java:187)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:161)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer(SocketInputBuffer.java:82)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:278)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:138)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56)
        at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259)
        at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.jav
a:286)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:257
)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java
:230)
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273)
        at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:684)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:486)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:118)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
        at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:173)
        ... 10 common frames omitted
```

I use pre-packaged war file downloaded from Releases page.
Version 4.0.0

Interesting part is when I run microservice I don't get this error. It happens only with gateway.

Also when creating new gateway and run it exception also not appear. It happens after 1 day and after a day if you got this exception you get this every time...

Comment: What does "When I run Gateway" mean?

Comment: @NicoHaase When I start gateway application.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error using the default configuration. The solution lies on the error message itself which is to increase the `peer-node-read-timeout-ms` value (default value is 200).

Go to your `application.yml`

```
server:
        # see discussion about enable-self-preservation:
        # https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/3654
        enable-self-preservation: false
        peer-node-read-timeout-ms: 5000
```

Comment: You could also add --eureka.server.peer-node-read-timeout-ms=10000 during running registry server war file.